# Shell Command move to the beginning faster

Tags: shell

I sometimes need to run a very long shell command, and I don't want to copy the long command to an editor and edit it there.

Is there a way in the shell to move the cursor quickly in instead of holding the left key for almost a minute and get to the most left?

Like move the cursor by word when you hold some key?
Or a combo could jump to the beginning of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash in the default mode, `ctrl-e` should do that for you.

Also helpful: `Ctrl-x-e` will take your current command line and open it in an editor, chosen via `$EDITOR`. (see [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3181/bash-hotkey-to-put-current-commandline-to-text-editor))

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in almost all shells, control-A will jump to the beginning of the line, and control-E to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash shell you can use control-a to jump to the start of the line, control-e to jump to the end.

More explanation and commands [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html).